# Pass argument to the function hidden in variable

Tags: r

this is a function which **can't be changed**:

```
foo <- function(y = 0, x = "no") {
  print(x)
}
```

I never know how the argument to pass will be called. Here it is `x` but sometimes it is `a` and sometimes `b` and so on...  I get the information in variable `argName`. So now `argName = "x"`
variable `arg` which contains the argument to pass to the `foo` function:

```
arg <- paste0(argName, "=\"yes\"")
```

now I want to pass `arg` to the arguments of `foo` to evaluate the same as:

```
foo(x="yes")
```

so how to do this? this was my tries:

```
foo(arg)
foo(`arg`)
foo('arg')
foo("arg")
foo(noquote(arg))
foo(noquote(`arg`))
foo(noquote('arg'))
foo(noquote("arg"))
foo(eval(arg))
foo(eval(noquote(arg))
```

Comment: Why can't it be `arg = list(x = "yes"); do.call(foo, arg)` as you would usually do?

Comment: because I never know the name of the argument. Sometimes it is called `x` and sometimes `a`, sometimes `b`... I get in in another variable... Edited my example.

Comment: You should simply fix the creation of `arg` then: `argName <- "x"; 
argValue <- "yes"; setNames(list(argValue), argName)`Or does this come from outside R (usually still a bad design)?